# Docker volume based on host directory contains only files owned by root (none owned by the user), and also contains some other random files

Tags: docker-compose

Using a `docker-compose.yml` file, I want to mount a host directory inside my container. First, I checked the see if I'd be overwriting anything important within the **container**:

```
# ls -al /etc/ssl
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun  4 22:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jun  9 23:38 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  4 22:29 certs
```

And how about the `certs` subdirectory within the **container**?

```
# ls -al /etc/ssl/certs
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun  4 22:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jun  4 22:29 ..
```

Ok, all clear.

Here's the host directory that I intend to mount from the **host**:

```
$ ls -al /etc/ssl
total 232
drwxr-xr-x   11 root           wheel     352 Jun  9 15:10 .
drwxr-xr-x  119 root           wheel    3808 Jun  9 14:21 ..
-rw-r--r--@   1 cameronhudson  wheel     466 Jun  9 14:32 README.md
drwxr-xr-x    5 cameronhudson  wheel     160 Jun  9 15:09 cameronhudson.info
drwxr-xr-x    4 cameronhudson  wheel     128 Jun  9 15:09 cameronhudson8.com
-rw-r--r--    1 root           wheel  196928 Mar 20 22:24 cert.pem
drwxr-xr-x    2 root           wheel      64 Aug 17  2018 certs
drwxr-xr-x    5 cameronhudson  wheel     160 Jun  9 15:09 iskprinter.com
drwxr-xr-x    5 cameronhudson  wheel     160 Jun  9 15:09 kronn8.com
-rw-r--r--    1 root           wheel     745 Aug 17  2018 openssl.cnf
-rw-r--r--    1 root           wheel    1006 Aug 17  2018 x509v3.cnf
```

As we can see, this directory contains a mix of files and directories, some owned by `cameronhudson`, and some owned by `root`.

Here's the `docker-compose.yml` file I'm using:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  webserver:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - /etc/ssl:/etc/ssl
```

After performing `docker-compose up --build` as host user `cameronhudson`, this is how the `/etc/ssl` directory inside the **container** looks:

```
# ls -al /etc/ssl
total 259
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root     60 Feb 13 10:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   4096 Jun  9 23:44 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 232598 Jan 29 16:27 cert.pem
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root     60 Feb 13 10:29 certs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    414 Dec 17 16:36 ct_log_list.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    414 Dec 17 16:36 ct_log_list.cnf.dist
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   2048 Feb 13 10:28 misc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10911 Dec 17 16:36 openssl.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10911 Dec 17 16:36 openssl.cnf.dist
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   2048 Feb 13 10:28 private
```

It's bizarre. Some things you'll notice:

- None of the files on the host owned by `cameronhudson` are present.
- All of the files on the host owned by `root` are present.
- There are other files present that do not exist in the host directory at all, such as `ct_log_list.cnf`, a file, and `private`, an empty directory.

I run Docker as `cameronhudson` on the host (without `sudo`). If the files in the container were exclusively owned by `cameronhudson`, that would be understandable. However, for the opposite to happen - running the container as `cameronhudson` and having access to files exclusively owned by `root` - I do not understand that at all...

How can I get access all files in the host directory? Ideally, getting rid of these random files like `ct_log_list.cnf` would be nice, too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this wasn't working because the `etc` directory is a symlink, and Docker does not follow symlinks by default.

```
Camerons-Air:IskPrinter-Site cameronhudson$ ls -al / | grep etc
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root  wheel     11 Oct 27  2018 etc -> private/etc
```

However, this doesn't explain what is up with some files being absent, and other random files appearing with the container. The other time I tried to have Docker follow a symlink, it simply gave an error saying that the directory or file did not exist.